# Storing a string token into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, token

I am using C++ to tokenize a string using a delimiter and I can output the current token using cout in a while loop. What I would like to do is store the current value of the token in an array so that I may access it later. Here is the code I have now:

```
string s = "Test>=Test>=Test";
string delimiter = ">=";
vector<string> Log;
int Count = 0;
size_t pos = 0;
string token;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
token = s.substr(0, pos);
strcpy(Log[Count].c_str(), token.c_str());
Count++;

s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```

Comment: Surely this doesn't compile. How can you `strcpy()` into the result of a `c_str()` call?? You should simply `push_back()` the token into the Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `push_back` on the vector. It will do a copy for the token into the vector for you. No need to keep count; no need for `strcpy`:

```
string s = "Test>=Test>=Test";
string delimiter = ">=";
vector<string> Log;
size_t pos = 0;
string token;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    Log.push_back(token);
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`push_back()` will do what you need.